# Is there a term or word for someone who fears homophobes?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, word-usage, phobias

Can you think of a single term or word for someone who dislikes or fears a homophobic person?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tue following is a rare term, probably the best way to express the concept is *"fear of homophobia*":

***[Homophobiaphobia](http://www.yourdictionary.com/homophobiaphobia)*** , (homophobia phobia, homophobia- phobia):

> - (rare) Antipathy towards homophobia and/or homophobes.
>
>   - Origin
>       homophobia +‎ -phobia

(English Wiktionary) and  [Urban Dictionary](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=homophobiaphobia)

Comment: I was thinking something along the same lines, Josh. Thanks for your input